# How to start both Angular app and WebApi service from VSCode on F5 or Ctrl+F5

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have top-level folder Homepage with the following structure:

```
--Homepage
----Client <- Angular app, created with `ng new` command
----Server <- .NET Core WebApi, created with `dotnet new webapi` command
```

I open VSCode at Homepage level:

[image]

I have these extensions installed:

[image]

**Question**

If I want to use single VSCode environment to work on both projects, Client and Server, is it possible to bind F5 (or Ctrl+F5) to start both projects together?

Client app I start using `ng serve` (it will run on http port 4200)
Server app I start using `dotnet run` (it will run on https port 5001)

I have just one common .vscode folder on Homepage (root level):

By default, when first created, the content of launch.json was this:

```
{
   // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
   // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
   // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Server/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/Server.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Server",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "launchBrowser": {
                "enabled": true,
                "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
                "windows": {
                    "command": "cmd.exe",
                    "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
                },
                "osx": {
                    "command": "open"
                },
                "linux": {
                    "command": "xdg-open"
                }
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ,]
}
```

So, when I press F5 it builds and start the Server app, the page opens at https://localhost:5001, from there I can navigate to https://localhost:5001/api/values and see WebApi works.

But the Client app doesn't start at all.

So, I thought if I add Debugger for Chrome extension's settings to launch.json, it should work, so I clicked on Add Configuration and added corresponding section:

[image]

```
{
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Chrome",
    "url": "http://localhost:4200",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
},
```

I changed port from 8080 to 4200, since ng serve hosts on port 4200

But it does not start the Client app.

**Please advice. Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

I have similar (node.js for API) and spent quite some times couldn't resolved, for example use `&&` or `&`. Result is either API up or Angular up, never the both.

Anyway I finally realized have both Api and UI in the same folder/project/solution is not practical. An API is not specific to an UI, it's a universal DLL/service, should be siting somewhere by itself. So I separated them into two diff folders and have 2 VSC instances to run them:

1. start the API in debug mode
2. in 2nd VSC, run `ng serve` and let it take time to build
3. when ng says "Compiled successfully" go to launch.json to start the debug entry associated with Chrome

they work perfectly.